# Reject all connections except from a specific IP

Tags: ubuntu, security, iptables, firewall

I've installed a database on Ubuntu that I'll connect to it from my other server remotely on port 27017.

This server I want to use only as a storage for my other server. I requested the host support to block all the connections except from one specified IP.

He did, but I still could connect from home. He reasoned that he blocked all IPs from accessing the services running on all the familiar default ports like 80, 25, 21, etc. so did the same for 27017.

With this setting, can I be sure that my database is not open to the world?! thanks.

Comment: Instead of blocking individual services, deny from all to all and then allow from `specific_ip` to your mongodb port (isn't 27017 the default port for mongo?).  I'd also consider running mongo on a different port to avoid random attempts at connecting, although the firewall should stop.  How to do all of this? Depends on how firewall was initially configured, either through `iptables` commands or by using `ufw`

Comment: Have you checked mongodb official docs ? - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/

Comment: @nwildner Thanks, no first time I see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to block which the database uses.

The more interesting question might be how that is done.

```
iptables -F INPUT # deletes all rules
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
: maybe allow other services here
iptables -A INPUT -s $allowed_source_address -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

This would block every new incoming connection except for those from the allowed IP to the database.

**blocking the database only**

```
iptables -F INPUT # deletes all rules
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s $allowed_source_address -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 -j DROP
```

Comment: Thanks @Hauke .. this will block other IPs only from connecting to port 27017, but still can connect to other services?

Comment: @Blendester No, see my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much. sorry I'm new in Linux, should I replace `$allowed_source_address` with `$xx.xx.xx.xx` with $ sign or without it?

Comment: @Blendester Without. `$` marks a variable i.e. both the `$` and the following name are replaced by the value of the variable.